# SharePoint 2010 workflows Will not delete properly

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow

I have a workflow that I am creating in SharePoint Designer 2010.  The issue I am running into is every time I publish a new version of the workflow, an older version keeps running.  I have tried removing all instances of the workflow and then republishing the workflow, but it keeps returning a variable that no longer exists to my log.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you publish a workflow, it will throw all the instances of that workflow to an old version. Check your local variables and association variables. Also, try to close SP Designer completely and connect back to the site, open the workflow, and publish again.

Comment: So even if I remove all of the old instances of the workflow the variables can still hold their values?

Comment: If you don't use a variable in SharePoint Designer, the variable will still exist. You need to delete the variable in the workflow in order for it to be affected.